# An Function that turns $\mathbb Z$ into $\mathbb Q$

Tags: functions

How to prove, that $f(x)$ with a domain of  $\mathbb Z$ and a range of  $\mathbb Q$, and is monotonically increasing  doesn't exists? (a problem on my exam paper)

I think that the number of elements in  $\mathbb Z$ and the elements in  $\mathbb Q$ is equal, so i think there can be a $f(x)$. However, I just couldn't find it?

I'm a bit confused, because i think that, suppose , like in every $(x,x+1]$, ($x$ is a whole number) there is only a whole number, $x+1$, but there is a infinite amount of numbers rational numbers. And I can divide $\mathbb Z$ into a infinite number of $(x,x+1]$. So why is the number of elements in  $\mathbb Z$ and the elements in  $\mathbb Q$ is equal? I've heard about it, but I just couldn't understand.

And if the number of elements in  $\mathbb Z$ and the elements in  $\mathbb Q$ is equal, then I think with any element in $\mathbb Q$ ($q$), I can find a element in  $\mathbb Z$ (I call it $p$), that $f(p)=q$. Then I think there is a $f(x)$. However, the problem tells me to prove that it is wrong!

Comment: Consider $f(0), f(1)$.  Prove there is some rational number between them.  How could you get that one?

Comment: Note:  I am assuming you want this function to be surjective.  If you drop that condition, then the identity map is an example.

Comment: @lulu I think that's a safe assumption, considering they specify that the _range_ is $\Bbb Q$. But some do get range and codomain mixed up, so better safe than sorry I guess.

Comment: @Arthur From my experience, in most areas of math the set $\{f(x): x\in A\}$ is called the image of $f$, while the range can be a larger set. But specifically in set theory, the image is often called range.

Comment: To your last comment - there are bijections between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ as there are between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ which is another way of saying they have the same cardinality, however this exercise shows that any such bijection (or any surjection for that matter) cannot be monotonically increasing. And note we are assuming the *standard* orders on all these sets.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Q$ is monotonically increasing. If $f$ is constant, then its range is certainly not the whole of $\Bbb Q$. So suppose $f$ is not constant. Then there exists $n\in\Bbb Z$ such that $f(n)<f(n+1)$.

But then how can $q=\frac12(f(n)+f(n+1))$ be in the range of $f$? If $m\le n$ then $f(m)\le f(n)<q$; and if $m\ge n+1$ then $f(m)\ge f(n+1)>q$. So $f(m)$ can never equal $q$.

Comment: A very decent argument.

Comment: Thank you a lot!